# How to get the $(ProjectDir) path in a Visual Studio native C++ Unit Testing using CppUnitTestFramework?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I need to be able to retrieve the project directory path of my unit testing in order to load some files required by the tests. I don't want to hard-code it in case the solution structure and absolute paths changes in the future.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, this is how I did it:

1. In my project Properties -> Configuration -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor I added this preprocessor definition `UNITTESTPRJ="$(ProjectDir)."`
2. Then in my cpp file I did:

`#define STRINGIFY(x) #x`

`#define EXPAND(x) STRINGIFY(x)`

```
string s = EXPAND(UNITTESTPRJ);
s.erase(0, 1); // erase the first quote
s.erase(s.size() - 2); // erase the last quote and the dot
string my_project_dir = s;
```

The stupid `.` at the end was necessary to escape the trailing `\"` in the project directory.