# Visual Studio unit test using files with relative path

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-c++

I have a Visual Studio unit test project where I need to read in from some file.

I am trying to set up the unit test project to read the files from a path relative to the project location so that it works also on the build server.

The directory where the project is located completely different from the location of the executable. It is sth like C:\Dir1\Dir2...\Dirn\Project

The directory where the test is run is 
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW

So I am not sure how I can read a file from a path relative to the location where the project resides instead of where the executable is.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Let's try to narrow this down a bit. How would you define a relative path?

Comment: I usually get stuff. But here I just don't get what you are trying to accomplish. Could you elaborate? Is it that you want to go relative from where you are running? Depending on that is usually not a good idea as the path can change. I would set a registry key to where your app is running and work from that.

Comment: Actually on windows it's ptretty easy to get the location of the executable without invoking the registry: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks @user4581301 I didn't know about that one. I've always let the installer set a key. I only set two keys, so now I could be down to one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to my problem.

You can define a preprocessor macro that is set as $(ProjectDir) and use this macro later on to get the path to the project directory, and therefore be able to use relative paths in the unit test project.

The solution is explained here: [How to get the $(ProjectDir) path in a Visual Studio native C++ Unit Testing using CppUnitTestFramework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150708/how-to-get-the-projectdir-path-in-a-visual-studio-native-c-unit-testing-usi)

Thank you.